# Swift 4 JSONDecoder Complex Data Missing Key

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I have been struggling with this for over a day now and Im not sure why I keep getting the Missing Key error when I clearly defined the key in my struct. Your help would be really appreciated. Please help clear up my confusion on how to decode nested types in JSON.

I am trying to parse the following JSON response but keep getting the Missing Key error message when I run my app.  Below is the message I get back from the service.

Here is the JSON resonse

```
{
    UserInfo =     {
        ApplicationArea =         {
            CreationDateTime = "2018-02-11 21:34:40.646000";
            MfgCode = PSUN;
            Sender = DM;
        };
        ServiceStatus =         {
            StatusCode = 0;
            StatusDescription = Success;
            System = "Product Info";
        };
        UserInfoDataArea =         {
            Email = "john@example.com";
            Locale = "en_US";
            UserId = 3;
            UserName = jdoe;
        };
    };
}
```

Here is the ERROR

```
    Missing Key: applicationArea 
Debug description: No value associated with key applicationArea ("ApplicationArea").
```

Below is my struct code for getting the request and to decode the response.

```
    struct UserInfo:Codable {

        struct ApplicationArea:Codable {
            let creationDateTime: String
            let mfgCode: String
            let sender: String

            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case creationDateTime = "CreationDateTime"
                case mfgCode = "MfgCode"
                case sender = "Sender"
            }
        }
        let applicationArea: ApplicationArea

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case applicationArea = "ApplicationArea"
        }    
    }
```

Code for creating the request

```
let apiMethod = HTTPMethod.post

Alamofire.request(
    loginURL!,
    method: apiMethod,
    parameters: params,
    encoding: URLEncoding.default,
    headers: header)
    .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            print(response.result.value)

            let result = response.data
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let userDetails = try decoder.decode(UserInfo.self, from: result!)
                    print("Response \(userDetails)")
            } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
                print("Missing Key: \(key)")
                print("Debug description: \(context.debugDescription)")
            } catch {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you also share a part of the JSON response? Hard to see whether you've set everything up correctly without that

Comment: hi @donnywals, i have edited my post, you can see json response.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake: You're ignoring the root object, the outermost dictionary containing the `UserInfo` key.

Create a `Root` struct

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let userInfo : UserInfo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case userInfo = "UserInfo" }
}
```

And decode

```
let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: result!)
let userDetails = root.userInfo
```

Comment: thank you, Your suggestion worked!  i though the root object was already in scope but I was mistaken.